# Ambigous reference when agg in Pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to make a simple agg function in my output df. As you can see below, I try to sum a column.

I think the problem comes from the fact that both joins have inside the 'trx_detail_total_amount' column.

Here is the code used:

```
output = (df2
         .groupby()
         .agg(f.sum('trx_detail_total_amount').alias('total_gross_turnover'))
        )
```

The error that I get from Databricks:

> AnalysisException: Reference 'trx_detail_total_amount' is ambiguous, could be: ...

I've tried the following solution:

```
output = (df2
         .groupby()
         .agg(f.sum('trx_detail_total_amount' as 'solution').alias('total_gross_turnover'))
        )
```

The error that I get from Databricks:

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Any clue?

Thanks!

Comment: The only way around this issue is to rename your columns **before** joining. Could you show your code for joining the dataframes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an alias in your join step, before the aggregation. Example

```
df.columns
['id', 'subject', 'mark']

df1.columns
['id', 'mark']
```

Error replication:

```
dfj=df.join(df1,df["id"]==df["id"])
df2=dfj.groupBy().agg(sum('mark').alias('total_marks')).show(10,truncate=False)
```

`org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Reference 'mark' is ambiguous, could be: mark, mark.`

After adding alias:

```
dfj=df.alias("t1").join(df1.alias("t2"),df["id"]==df1["id"])
df2=dfj.groupBy().agg(sum('t1.mark').alias('total_marks')).show(10,truncate=False)

+-----------+
|total_marks|
+-----------+
|91055.0    |
+-----------+
```

Note that you can also do

```
dfj=df.alias("t1").join(df1.alias("t2"),col("t1.id")==col("t2.id"))
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how you joined the dataframe, but you can rename the column before joining the dataframe, something similar as below:

```
df1 = df1.withColumnRenamed('trx_detail_total_amount', 'trx_detail_total_amount_1')
df2 = df0.join(df1, ...)

output = (df2
         .groupby()
         .agg(f.sum('trx_detail_total_amount').alias('total_gross_turnover'))
         )
```

In this way you can avoid having duplicated column names in the joined dataframe `df2`.